# What size torsion spring does my garage door need?

Tags: garage-door

I have a 17'x7' insulated garage door and one of my torsion springs broke last night.  The previous owner said that they replaced the original ones with smaller versions because that's all the store had in stock at the time. I want to get the most appropriate size for my door but I dont know what needs to be considered.  What size torsion springs should I use, or how can I figure it out?

[image: Spring]

Comment: They are usually rated for the height and weight of the door. Be very cautious I have seen these springs do a huge amount of damage when improperly installed, contact the manufacturer and they will probably tell you the correct size,,, never go smaller that's how to get hurt it puts more stress on the spring than it was designed for.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks - any pro-tips or suggestions on how to execute this safely?

Comment: As Ed Beal said, the ONLY safe DIY way is to use the *exact* spring for your door's make and model, as recommended by the manufacturer. You should be able to find a nameplate or label somewhere on the door or frame. I was injured by a falling garage door when I was young and ambitious/dumb, now I call a licensed, bonded, insured pro for garage door hardware.

Comment: Wrong spring is bad news, and it makes the door hard to open or control-- oh wait, you use a power opener, don't you?   If you had ever operated your door manually, you would know you had a sick door.  That's the trouble with openers.

Comment: I am not a pro in this area and have had bad things happen to the point I will pay to have it done when I don't have the correct replacement parts even then saving a few bucks after some bad experiances is better left to the pros with openers even though they are simple in principal ,,, just my opinion after some close calls in the past.pp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every door based on weight has has its own very specific spring or springs.  No guessing.  You can take your complete old spring to an overhead door company and they will get you the correct replacement. While we are on the subject, the changing of an overhead door spring is really not a job for the home DIY guy. This is dangerous.  If you have a high level mechanical aptitude, maybe; but watch the videos on YOU Tube first.  And be careful.

Comment: Thanks. I already replaced them and with it being my first time, I'd say it's pretty easy to do. Even balancing the door was straight forward. I see where the danger could arise but as long as you follow correct procedures and use proper equipment, it's very simple even for the average DIY'er.  I was overthinking this project as I do with everything I'm ignorant of. Glad I got to learn how to do it though.